# Java panel interface

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, paintcomponent

Im trying to make a pline drawing program. when I try to repaint all of the lines(after creating a new one) only the last one is draw out.The problem might be in repainting.

Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

Code is here:

```
public class Kimp extends JFrame {

private ArrayList<Point[]> pointsArray = new ArrayList<>();
private Point points[] = new Point[10000];
private int pointCounter = 0;

public Kimp () {

     panel paintArea = new panel();
     add(paintArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

private class panel  extends JPanel {

    public panel () {
        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        this.addMouseListener(handler);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
    }

    @Override
     void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        try {


            for (Point[] p : pointsArray) {
                for(int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {                         
                    if (p[i].x == 0) {
                       continue;
                    } else {
                        if (p[i + 1].x == 0) {
                            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                            g.drawLine(p[i].x, p[i].y, p[i].x, p[i].y);
                        } else {
                            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                            g.drawLine(p[i].x, p[i].y, p[i + 1].x, p[i + 1].y);
                        }
                    } 
                } 
            }
            points = preFill(points);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }                  
    }
}

private class HandlerClass implements MouseListener , MouseMotionListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        points[pointCounter++] = e.getPoint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        points[pointCounter] = e.getPoint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

}

public static Point[] preFill (Point[] points) {
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i] = new Point(-999,-999);
    }
    return points;
}
```

}

Comment: `private Point points[] = new Point[10000];` - just **don't**. Use ArrayList for this! Because what's the purpose of loading so much memory, when you don't know how much you will use? And secondly, don't catch `NullPointerException`

Comment: Plus a line may use way more than 10000 points, so do not restrict the amount arbitrarily (or only if you see a clear performance issue after a certain amount of points, by trial-and-error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly rewrote your code to simplify it as much as possible. You may be able to better understand the concepts behind it.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Kimp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Kimp!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(new CanvasPanel());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class CanvasPanel extends JPanel {
    private final List<List<Point>> lines = new LinkedList<List<Point>>();
    private List<Point> points = new LinkedList<Point>();

    public CanvasPanel() {
        addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        for (List<Point> line : lines)
            drawLine(line, g);
        drawLine(points, g);
    }

    private void drawLine(List<Point> points, Graphics g) {
        if (points.size() < 2) return;

        Point p1 = points.get(0);

        for (int i=1, n=points.size(); i<n; i++) {
            Point p2 = points.get(i);

            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);

            p1 = p2;
        }
    }

    private MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            points.add(e.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            points.add(e.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (points.size() > 1) {
                lines.add(points);
                points = new LinkedList<Point>();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @fusi0n I just figured that out, sorry :) I added the missing behavior, see the code now. A line is added to the list on mouse release, if it contains more than 1 point.

Comment: Another way to print all the lines while reducing the required memory as much as possible would be to not clear the canvas with the "fillRect()" call. You can draw as much as you want since the previous lines will never be erased. You just draw a line between the last point and the new one in mouseDragged(), and that's all. A simple reference to the last point is sufficient.

Comment: If i need to undo the line I just made ... how do I do that then ?

Comment: You can't with the latter option. If you want to do that, you need to store the lines like in the code I gave you, and just remove the last item and call repaint().

Comment: Great, then I understood it correctly. Any hints what methods/event /actions/ways I should read about if I want to move a line that has been drawn on the panel? Move by holding down a key(know how to handle that) and then dragging it.

Comment: Just implement a KeyListener to know if a given key has been pressed/released. Add a if-branch in the mousePressed and mouseDragged, and if you want to move a line, just add some value to every point coordinate of that line.

Comment: Great, atleast I wasn´t going to do that the wrong way. I really appreaciate all your help.

Comment: Nice to hear :) Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

```
private ArrayList<Point[]> pointsArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is a list of Point[]. Here only one `private Point points[] = new Point[10000];` is allocated. Which means that each time you add `points` into `pointArray`, you are adding the same instance of `points`.

When you change the elements of `points`, all the existing `Point[]` in `pointArray` is updated. Since all the elements are referring to the same `points`.

Allocate new Point[] when drawing a new line.

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting your points array every time you painted it (preFillPoints() is called in paint()). Your pointsArray (which should be called pointsList for gods sake) is completely meaninless, you add the same points[] array each time the mouse is released.

The code makes no sense. You only need the list *or* the array. Not both. Declare a List<Point> (not Point[]) and just add a new Point every time the mouse moves.